# how to implement Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) in phone gap app

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, aslr

We are building phone gap app. Our application currently making use of Internet,Gallery, Camera, background services. At this point we haven't any sensitive records at client side (But may be in future). For this reason some of our clients making requirement for the application makes use of Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR).
I currently have no idea whether this is already enabled or not. How to implement this in phone gap app or is there any phone gap plugin to support ASLR?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: You linked to your answer.

Comment: Yes mobile OS do support this.But is this already enabled for all apps? or We have to enable this feature for our app manually?